# Fourier Transform Duality Theorem scaling problem?

Tags: fourier-transform

From the duality theorem if:
$$
FT(x(t)) = X(w)
$$
Then
$$
FT(X(t)) = 2\pi x(-w)
$$

If I choose $X(t) = 1$, then $X(w) = 1$ thus $x(t) = \delta(t)$.

Now plugging back into the second equation:
$$
FT(1) = 2\pi \delta(-w) = 2\pi \delta(w)
$$

Which is wrong, the general shape of the result is correct, indeed a constant in time domain will be an impulse at zero in frequency domain, but why is it scaled by $2\pi$? this $2\pi$ has to be removed somehow.

Now I usually use the duality theorem for finding inverse fourier transform, but I was trying to find a way to find fourier transform of $sinc(t)$ and I expect it to be a square pulse but I can't get the scaling right.

Comment: What is your definition of the Fourier Transform?  With the definition I use, FT(X(t)) = x(-w).  For your definition, everything above may be correct.

Comment: Why do you think that the factor $2\pi$ is incorrect. It is indeed correct, $FT(\delta)=1$ and $FT(1)=2\pi\delta.$

Comment: If you want to use table look-ups of forward transforms interchangably as their inverse transforms, then you should use tables with the forward transform defined as $F(s) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-2\pi i x s} dx$ .  Then you won't have to worry about those constants that show up because of the radians units.

Answer (score 0):

I am now taking a communications course and have successfully got to know the issue, simply speaking Fourier Transform is defined as

$$
G(f) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(t) e^{-j2\pi ft} \,dt
$$

Which can be re-written in terms of $\omega$ as following

$$
G(\omega) = G(j\omega) = G(e^{j\omega}) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(t) e^{-j\omega t} \,dt
$$

Now the Inverse-Fourier Transform is defined as

$$
g(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} G(f) e^{j2\pi ft} \,df
$$

And from a quite simple observation by adjusting exponential to have a negative power and swapping variables $t$ and $f$

$$
g(-t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} G(f) e^{-j2\pi ft} \,df
$$

$$
g(-f) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} G(t) e^{-j2\pi ft} \,dt
$$

This in a simple form means

$$
\text{If} ~ g(t)\Leftrightarrow G(f) ~ \text{, then} ~ G(t) \Leftrightarrow g(-f)
$$

Now in my example I choose $G(t) = 1$ which by comparing to the following and plugging back into the theorem means

$$
g(t) = \delta (t) ~\text{then} ~ G(f) = 1 \\
G(t) = 1 ~ \text{then} ~ g(-f) = \delta (f) ~ \text{and since dirac function is even} ~ g(f) = \delta (f)
$$

The mistake I had is that I was solving assuming the frequency version of Inverse-Fourier Transform.